# Is there a way to programmatically determine the actual IP used for an endpoint in the Azure DevFabric?

Tags: azure, azure-compute-emulator

I'm hosting an IIS application under the Azure development fabric.

When an application is deployed to the Azure compute emulator, a temporary IIS application is created that listens on a port around 5100. Incoming requests from the public endpoint are redirected to this port.

It seems, though, that the Azure development fabric does not always use the public port that has been declared in the project configuration. So, for instance, our application should expose a public port 80 -- but when I run this it's almost always port 81, but sometimes port 82, and so on.

So I can ensure that URLs created in my application are correct, I'd like to know what this *external* port is.

Unfortunately I can't simply look at `Request.Url.Port`, as this is the port number of the temporary application -- typically 5100. `RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints`, doesn't work either as that also returns the ports as seen from the server, 5100 and following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out by using Reflector to look into csrun.exe.

It seems that the SDK DLL `Microsoft.ServiceHost.Tools.DevelopmentFabric` is the key to this, in particular the methods `FabricClient.GetServiceDeployments()` and `FabricClient.GetServiceInformation()`. So:

`using System;
    using Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric;`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FabricClient client = FabricClient.CreateFabricClient();

        foreach (string tenantName in client.GetServiceDeployments())
        {
            var information = client.GetServiceInformation(tenantName);
            foreach (var item in information)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3}", item.ContractName, item.InterfaceName, item.UrlSpecification, item.Vip));
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

What I'm after is returned as the `item.Vip`.

Note, obviously, that this will only work in the development fabric ... but that's what I was looking for here, anyway.

Comment: Curses. Looks like this only works for applications running as administrator, which of course a dev. fabric application won't be. I fear I'll need to write a little shim to do this...

Comment: Is this assembly still available?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using

```
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints
```

I am not sure atm, as I am not behind my pc, but will double check soon. Anyway, on each endpoint there is a property IPEndPoint which has Port as well. If you get the public endpoint as well (which I think you do for current role instance) you should be able to get the address from there.

Hope it helps...

Comment: Been there and tried that -- unfortunately those are the "temporary" endpoints, e.g. 5100. I've updated my question.

Comment: I was afraid of that =/ Like I said, I didn't have a way to check... You do get the internal endpoints only. But yes, as @Michael pointed out, that is a bug in the emulator, so the port number shouldn't be an issue. For the url part, we are also looking for a solution, but so far have unfortunately resorted to storing the URL in the config file.

Comment: `csrun` manages to figure this out (and, by the way, doesn't seem to increment ports nearly as often) - I'll keep digging.

Comment: What you could do is use the Azure Management API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460806.aspx) and get the link of the current deployment (RoleEnvironment.DeploymentID). But for this to work, you need to include your management certificate which is not always a good thing.

Comment: No good: the Service Management API doesn't work in the dev. fabric: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/11c0b0cb-94e0-4779-aa90-4f659c09e36b/

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for the "wrong" port, like 81/82, etc is that the desired port is busy.

Probably you have some other app listening to port 80, so it is never available. Also, I've seen several times when the Azure compute instance in emulator does not shutdown quicky enough, so if you start a new instance it gets next port, etc. If I kill it, wait a bit and start again - it gets desired port.

It should never be a problem in production, which is probably why it is not exposed via API. And during testing just make sure you don't have conflicts with other apps, and that you allow some time to let compute notes shutdown cleanly and release ports.

Comment: All this is true. However, our application needs to create custom URLs while it's executing, and we can't make relative URLs as the hostname has to change. So our navigation routines need to know what the client-visible port number might be.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the dev fabric assembly to work for me (looks like API has changed), so I resorted to parsing the output of "csrun /status" to find the IP address of a given role name. Here's some code for getting the IP, but you'd have to do a small amount of extra work to grab the ports.

```
public static string GetEmulatorIPAddress(string roleName)
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
        psi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Emulator\csrun.exe";
        psi.Arguments = "/status";
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        DataReceivedEventHandler errorHandler = (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
            {

            };

        string lastIPAddress = null;
        string foundIPAddress = null;

        DataReceivedEventHandler dataHandler = (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            string line = e.Data;
            if (line != null && foundIPAddress == null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("EndPoint: http://"))
                {
                    int ipStart = line.IndexOf("://") + "://".Length;
                    int ipEnd = line.IndexOf(":", ipStart);
                    lastIPAddress = line.Substring(ipStart, ipEnd - ipStart);
                }

                if (line.Trim() == roleName)
                {
                    foundIPAddress = lastIPAddress;
                }
            }
        };

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.ErrorDataReceived += errorHandler;
        p.OutputDataReceived += dataHandler;
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        p.Start();
        p.BeginOutputReadLine();
        p.BeginErrorReadLine();

        p.WaitForExit();

        return foundIPAddress;
    }
```